# Elastic search term query not working if used field.keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have below mapping for elastic search

```
{
   "2021-05-ui":{
      "mappings":{
         "userinfo":{
            "properties":{
               "address":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                     "keyword":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "name":{
               "type":"keyword"
            },
            "userId":{
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to use the term query on userId field like below its doesn't work , but when i remove `.keyword` from below query its work , i want the query which match exact value for userId field

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "userId.keyword": "test@user.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

i want the query with  `"userId.keyword"` only since other environments its has both the text and keyword mapping , could you please suggest which query we can use to get the exact match , i tried using match,match_phrase but didnt help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`userId` field is of `keyword` type, which means it uses keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer. In this case, you will be getting the result only for the exact match

Since `userId` is of `keyword` type and there is no field for `userId.keyword`, you have to use `userId` for term query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "userId": "test@user.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**However if you want to store `userId` field as of both `text` and `keyword` type, then you can [update your index mapping as shown below to use multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#add-multi-fields-existing-field-ex)**

```
PUT /_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then reindex the data again. After this, you will be able to query using the `"userId"` field as of `keyword` type and `"userId.raw"` as of `text` type